# How can i pass editTexts from Activity class to nonActivity

Tags: java, android

My Activity Login has edittext's value first entered by username and second value by password. I'm trying to pass this values of editText from Activity Class to nonActivityClass(Java Class).

Does exist any way to do this?

Comment: How would you give any value to some other Java class?

Comment: I want to make general class for validate login with api , to be more specific what i want to do is to take this edit texts from Activity Main and pass to another nonActivity   class , my url look like this  https:/localhost:8080/home/ +username + /inbox.json?auth=ba"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In MyLoginAcitivy:**

```
yourButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        String username = yourEditTextUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = yourEditTextPassword.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,nonActivityClass.class);
        intent.putExtra("username",username);
        intent.putExtra("password",password);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**In nonActivityClass:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAY_OUT);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null){
      String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
      String password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you want to do that. But you can do this using Preferences.
At your Activity save your data to Pref and load them at your Class

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with the data, I'm not sure what your issue is. You can use a Class with a Static method which can accept username and passwords then do your checking there or what ever operation you want after which you can return the result. There are other options to try out. Just like database classes which are not 'Activity classes', you can also pass values to them.

Answer (score 0):

As in any normal class in Java with constructors:

```
User newuser = new User(uname, pwd); // in your activity
// in your class
public User(String uname,String pwd){
      this.uname = uname;
      this.pwd = pwd;
      }
```

Please also consider to learn [java basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) before use it in android.